# Final Kotlin class can not be mocked because method "should return Validator"

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to write unit tests for my [Javalin.io](https://javalin.io/) web application. There are [a few references](https://javalin.io/tutorials/mockito-testing) to Mockito being used for mocking the [Context objects](https://github.com/tipsy/javalin/blob/2df2fe0d05d47ae55afa9c1b8f1b1f03006da47d/javalin/src/main/java/io/javalin/http/Context.kt), which is Javalins way to give the user access to the incoming web requests. I am trying to mock the `.header(String)` method of the `Context` class because the unit under test is reading the "Authorization" header and performs a JWT check on it.

My pom contains a recent version of Mockito, which [should be able to mock final classes](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#mock-the-unmockable-opt-in-mocking-of-final-classesmethods):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have enabled the inline mock maker as described in the Mockito documentation by creating the file `resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` with the content `mock-maker-inline`.

Now I have a stupid test which mocks a `Context` object and should return "hello123" whenever the header() method of the context object is called. The following code is part of a *real* unit test but is enough to cause an exception when running the test:

```
  @Test
  void stupidTest1() {
    Context context = mock(Context.class);

    String test1 = "hello123";
    when(context.header("Authorization")).thenReturn(test1);
  }
```

and also tried this:

```
  @Test
  void stupidTest1() {
    Context context = mock(Context.class);

    String test1 = "hello123";
    given(context.header("Authorization")).willReturn(test1);
  }
```

Executing this test with `mvn test` fails with the exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 

String cannot be returned by header()
header() should return Validator
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.

    at my.package.stupidTest1(JavalinTest.java:28)
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? One point that is weird is that the test *sometimes* runs successfully, but fails most of the time, especially when running the `mvn test` command a few times in a row.

Comment: Could you please provide the source code for the class you're testing, and also the whole test class (latter for checking the correctness of annotations etc.)

Comment: @amseager Hi, the class I'm testing/mocking is linked above (Link "Context objects"). The test class has a single method which is shown above in its entirety, there are no other annotations. That's all there is in my test. Which is also why I'm wondering why the test is failing most of the times, but returns successfully in a small fraction of runs.

Comment: Another thing that is interesting: I have set up IntelliJ to run my test 100 times in a row. They either all fail (most of the times) or all succeed. I have adjusted my test method to mock a Java class (as opposed to the Kotlin Context class) and it is working reliably. I have the feeling something is going wrong when mocking that Kotlin class...

Comment: Can you share the context class? What is the return type for .header() method?

Comment: @RatishBansal it is part of the javalin.io framework. The link to the class is linked in the initial post.

Comment: @RatishBansal here is the method I want to use https://github.com/tipsy/javalin/blob/2df2fe0d05d47ae55afa9c1b8f1b1f03006da47d/javalin/src/main/java/io/javalin/http/Context.kt#L242-L243 -- BELOW that method I can see an overloaded method that returns Validator class. Maybe Mockito is using that method instead of the method I actually want to mock?

Comment: Looks like the library author forget to annotate the [reified method](https://github.com/tipsy/javalin/blob/55e6997177ec4c492af0e615eee84e13b3557080/javalin/src/main/java/io/javalin/http/Context.kt#L250) with `JvmSynthetic` so that it is not called from Java. See https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-do-i-force-a-java-call-to-overloaded-kotlin-method-accepting-a-non-nulllable-parameter/12535/4. You should submit a [bug report](https://github.com/tipsy/javalin/issues/new?template=1_Bug_report.md)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce the issue at my local.
It seems there is an issue during classloading and Mockito cannot find the correct [method](https://github.com/tipsy/javalin/blob/2df2fe0d05d47ae55afa9c1b8f1b1f03006da47d/javalin/src/main/java/io/javalin/http/Context.kt#L246) every time. 
You can change the test as below to make sure it finds the correct header method. It worked at my local.

```
@Test
public void stupidTest1() {
    Context context = mock(Context.class);
    String test1 = "hello123";
    Validator<String> f = new Validator<String>("hello123","Value");
    when(context.header(test1,String.class)).thenReturn(f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works on my end as well. I'll create a bug ticket in Javalin's github page.

Comment: even though this compiles, it does not cause the mock to respond properly to `context.header("HeaderName")` because it never calls the `context.header("blahblah",String.class)` overload.

Comment: @j9dy, did this work for you? why did you mark it as resolved?

Comment: @Mobigital see https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1943#issuecomment-664853341

Comment: @Mobigital I just tested the comment in the link mentioned above but it still does not work. Does the accepted answer given in this stack overflow not work for you?

Comment: @j9dy, it compiles but the intercept doesn't work because of different signature being actually called (see my orig comment above). I ended up solving this by mocking HttpServletRequest that's passed to a real Context class and was able to mock headers that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
open class Context{

    fun header(name: String) : String {
        var token = "DEFAULT TOKEN"
        if(name == "AUTHORIZATION"){
            token =  "Bearer 01234"
        }
        return token
    }

}
```

Test Class:

```
open class ContextTest {

    var context: Context = mock()

    @Test
    fun testContextWhenHeaderIsAuth(){
        /* Return what the real method returns.*/
        whenever(context.header("AUTHORIZATION")).thenCallRealMethod()
        assertEquals("Bearer 01234", context.header("AUTHORIZATION"))

        /* Mocking the return value to be something you need*/
        whenever(context.header("AUTHORIZATION")).thenReturn("Bearer XXX")
        assertEquals("Bearer XXX", context.header("AUTHORIZATION"))
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, my application is a java application though and I'm trying to mock that final Kotlin class in java

Answer (score 0):

I tried several of the suggestions here and could not consistently get Mockito to work with io.javalin.http.Context.  It would work for a time and then stop working. Or it would work in the debugger but not when executed normally.

A Suggestion by @Mobigital worked for me.

Mock the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse.

```
@Test
public void get_csv() throws SQLException
{
    final HttpServletRequest request= mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    final HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    final Map<Class<?>, ?> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    // Mocking the Context was not working correctly.
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61792392/final-kotlin-class-can-not-be-mocked-because-method-should-return-validator
    Context ctx = new Context(request, response, map);
    
    when(request.getAttribute("database")).thenReturn(getConnection());

    when(request.getHeader(Header.ACCEPT)).thenReturn("text/csv"); 
    when(request.getQueryString()).thenReturn("my_param=some_value");

    LocationGroupController controller = new LocationGroupController(new MetricRegistry());
    controller.getAll(ctx);

    verify(response).setStatus(200);
    verify(response).setContentType("text/csv");
}
```

Comment: Javalin versions >4.0.0 will remove the reified Kotlin methods and thus make this workarounds obsolete